# using masterpage's UpdatePanel from contentpage

Tags: asp.net

Can I update masterpage's updatepanel from content page.

suppose that i have an updatepanel in masterpage like as follows..

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Can i change that Literal1's text from contentpage ?

If so - how?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure you can.

make sure you put both `Literal` on Master page & `Button` on content page inside `UpdatePanel`. in the `Button`'s click handler, you can update the `Literal` control on Master page

```
Literal literal1 = (Literal)Master.FindControl("Literal1");
```

Comment: This didnt work for me :/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447104/why-the-updatepanel-in-masterpage-not-updating-from-an-event-from-the-content-pa

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you can programatically add your sender as AsyncPostBackTrigger to your UpdatePanel.

```
UpdatePanel panel = (UpdatePanel)Master.FindControl("UpdatePanel1");
AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
trigger.ControlID = ((Control)sender).ID;
panel.Triggers.Add(trigger);
panel.DataBind();
Literal literal = Master.FindControl("Literal1") as Literal;
literal.Text = "some text";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find any control from the master page via code like this:

```
Literal literal = (Literal)Master.FindControl("Literal1");
```

Then you should be able to update the content of that literal.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's to

Özgür Kaplan

, I've produced my own solution:

I had to produce a warning message with jQuery.dialog, I've placed an UpdatePanel with an empty asp:label (UpdateMode="Conditional").

In Master.cs I've placed this Public Funcion:

```
        public void WarningUpdate(string childControlID, string eventName, string warningMessage)
    {
        lblWarningMessage.Text = warningMessage;            
        var trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger {ControlID = childControlID, EventName = eventName};
        upWarningMessage.Triggers.Add(trigger);
        upWarningMessage.DataBind();
        upWarningMessage.Update();
    }
```

In the Page, in some event (a Click one...) I've placed this code:

```
            var master = (FM) Master;
            if (master != null) master.WarningUpdate(((Control)sender).ID, "Click", "Devi prima selezionare una Provincia!");
```

And the result is:
[image]